# Catalogue Search Indexer Unknown Error

Tags: magento2, indexer

I'm having problems getting the Catalog Search indexer to complete. All other indexers are fine.

Here's the exact error taking from shell

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in 
/home/tbyte/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog- 
search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/Full.php on line 384
```

Inside full.php on line 384 is this:

```
$productIndex = [$productData['entity_id'] => $productsAttributes[$productData['entity_id']]];
```

indexer:status shows 0 in backlog but catalog search status as Reindex Required.

I've tried the following to no avail:

1. Reinstall of Magento by renaming env.php
2. Commands such as setup:di:compile, db-schema upgrades, cache:clean etc

This problem is stopping products from being displayed on the front end.

I'm running Magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has the same problem, I changed the PHP Version from 7.0 to 7.1 and enabled the same PHP Extensions and PHP Directives as previous version using EasyApache 4 in WHM. Import of products and reindex breezed through.